# How to quit Jupyter and become a better programmer?

Tags: python, version-control, jupyter-notebook, code-organization

I am a self-taught programmer coming from a scientific (non-programming) background. I discovered Jupyter early after I started using Python. And although I greatly enjoy using it (Jupyter), I feel that it somewhat hindered my ability to think ahead and write code that will be easy to maintain and interact with in the future.

I inevitably end up with these endless notebooks that are impossible to navigate and mostly consist of redundant code. I then tuck away some of the functions into text files. Make a copy of the notebook, delete a bunch of cells, and start over. Until the notebook becomes unmanageable again, then semi-refactor, make a copy, prune cells, and so on.

I feel that at this point I should learn some basic software design principles and practices (like version control and code organization). Is there a course or a lecture series you can recommend that might help me with that? I feel that any advice from you will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You could use Spyder and Git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This will help in learning version control from [official Git Documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

> This will also help in [Software development philosophies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_development_philosophies#Software_development_philosophies) from wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

Try sublime text editor. It is not an IDE but it is really good for coding and has a bunch of useful coding plugins. It is not free but has an unlimited free trial, in which you get all the features, and an occasional popup asking you to buy it. If you download it, you should also use some plugins to help you code python

I personally use these plugins:
Origami, Terminus, Kite & Anaconda

I f you don't like sublime or using a plain text editor, check out visual studio code, idle or thonny.
They are full IDEs (not code editors), and will thus have more features.
IDLE & thonny are beginner's IDEs and Visual Studio Code is a lot more powerful & complex

Now you have your Jupyter notebook replacement on to the version control

Instead of using git, use github. It is built on top of git, and is a lot easier.
If you don't already have a github account then create one. Now you have a version control system going. I am not going to go any deeper because i am not very good at github version control so check out [this site](https://ourcodingclub.github.io/tutorials/git/)